# How can I get black window borders in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-preview

In Windows 8, when I go into `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance` the amount of control over window colors is greatly reduced as compared to Windows 7.  The color controls do not allow you to make Window borders display in black.

Is there some other way to set the window border color in Windows 8?

**Edit 1:** Clearly the standard way does not work in Windows 8.  The question is, is there another way?  Perhaps through the registry for example?

**Edit 2:** I tried copying the values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM` from my Win7 system to the Win8 system without success (killing the 2 DWM processes after each change - they are automatically restarted and do use the new values).

Comment: Ahh, the beauty of dev previews is that they don't give a crap about fluff and colors.  At least in an ideal world. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 is a step backwards in customization.  The RTM version does make it possible to set the border to black and this also affects the title/caption bar.  Unlike previous versions of Windows, you can not change the text color and it is black.  So changing border elements to black makes it impossible to read the caption text.

Comment: downvote the truth

Answer (score 0):

They simply haven't added all the customization options in the dev preview yet; you probably won't see this until future beta/RC builds.  (You really shouldn't be using 8 as your daily driver, anyway, so a bit of visual ugly isn't a huge loss.)

Comment: Why the downvote?  This was true at the time.